# EmberJS view is not updating when updating an object in an array

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template where i have a table.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="customers">
<table>

    <tbody>
    {{#each nomday in allnominationdays}}
    <tr class="nomdays" {{action "saveNomDay" nomday on="focusOut"}}>
      <td>{{nomday.confirmedVolume}}</td>
      <td>{{nomday.variance}}</td>  
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>

</table>
</script>
```

In my controller i have a function which i call from the action saveNomDay defined on the tr.

```
update: function()
{
    console.log('Not Working');
    allnominationdays = this.get('allnominationdays');
    //this.set('allnominationdays',null);

    allnominationdays.objectAt(0).variance = 75;
    this.set('allnominationdays',allnominationdays);
},
```

But my view is not changing when i change the value of the object array. If i set the object array to null the template updates and shows no table. I am not sure what is breaking the binding for the view to update?

the code block updates the view when in a controller function but not when called on a action. But inside the action setting the array of object to null update the view and removes the entire table. Don't know what is going on. New in EmberJS

THanks,

Comment: Why you don't use Ember.set for changing object's properties (`variance`)? Try to use `Em.set(allnominationdays.objectAt(0), 'variance', 75)`.

Comment: thanks @Microfed Ember.set(allnominationdays.objectAt(0), 'variance', 75); works. I did not know of this set syntax. Also is there a similar get syntax to get only 1 object from array unlike what i have done as allnominationdays = this.get('allnominationdays');.

Comment: also @Micofed any insight into why the code works inside a controller function but not when fired from an action?

Comment: You can get first object from an Ember.Array by `array.get('firstObject')` (`this.get('allnominationdays.firstObject')` in your case) or array[0] (`objectAt` doing the same practically).

Comment: I'am not sure about your second question. In my opinion, controller's action and controller's function/method - are the same things if you look from the code inside these functions, so I can't say anything. :)

Comment: @microfed Ember.set(self.get('allnominationdays').objectAt(index),'confirmedVolume',data.confirmedVolume);                                so how to do set for a entire object to an object not set the property as you shown me here. I want to do like                                            Ember.set(self.get('allnominationdays').objectAt(index),data);  basically I am updating only one row of an array from a ajax save to update the row here. I can set each property but I guess i should be able to set the whole object to the new response data.

Answer (score 0):

I am too late but better late than never. This is happening because the view is getting rendered before the update in the value can propogate to the screen. Do something like the following code :

--template

```
    {{#if isVisible}}
    <table>

    <tbody>
    {{#each nomday in allnominationdays}}
    <tr class="nomdays" {{action "saveNomDay" nomday on="focusOut"}}>
      <td>{{nomday.confirmedVolume}}</td>
      <td>{{nomday.variance}}</td>  
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>

</table>
{{/if}}
```

--component / controller

```
self.set('isVisible',false);
var propgationPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            //update Value
            console.log("promise started");
            resolve();
            });
            propgationPromise.then(function(){
                console.log("promise stopped");     
                self.set('isVisible', true);
            });
```